# MySQL is not using prmary index

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM
    (`citations`)
        LEFT JOIN
    `projects` ON `projects`.`project_id` = `citations`.`project_id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `projects`.`user_id`
WHERE
    `users`.`role` = '0'
        AND `citations`.`created` BETWEEN 1360213200 AND 1360299599
        AND `citations`.`in_card` = '0'
        AND `citations`.`citation_id` NOT IN (SELECT 
            user_stats_citations.citation_id
        FROM
            user_stats_citations,
            user_stats FORCE INDEX (user_stats_type_index)
        WHERE
            user_stats_citations.user_stat_id = user_stats.id
                AND user_stats.type IN (69 , 70, 71, 75, 76));
```

I have those indexes on user table:

```
users            0  PRIMARY                             1  user_id      A                42836    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
users            1  users_industry_id_index             1  industry_id  A                  118    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               
users            1  users_sponsor_index                 1  sponsor      A                   12    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE
```

This is the output of EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
  id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra

  1 PRIMARY users   ALL PRIMARY \N  \N  \N  42836   100.00  Using where
  1 PRIMARY projects    ref PRIMARY\,projects_user_id_index projects_user_id_index  4   citelighter.users.user_id   1   100.00  Using where; Using index
  1 PRIMARY citations   ref citations_project_id_index  citations_project_id_index  4   citelighter.projects.project_id 4   100.00  Using index condition; Using where
  2 SUBQUERY    user_stats  range   user_stats_type_index   user_stats_type_index   2   \N  410768  100.00  Using where; Using index
  2 SUBQUERY    user_stats_citations    ref user_stats_citations_index_user_stat_id\,user_stats_citations_index_citation_id user_stats_citations_index_user_stat_id 8   citelighter.user_stats.id   1   100.00  \N
```

I tried to add FORCE INDEX on users LEFT JOIN but the index is not used. Can you help me to solve this, because this query is taking like 10 seconds on my local and 1 second on production environment.

Comment: FWIW, I like to do EXPLAINs with \G instead of ;

Comment: Also, "WHERE `users`.`role` = '0'" = INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that this predicate in the where clause: `WHERE users.role = '0'` turns your `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s, so you may as well just make them inner joins.

Secondly, MySQL has problems optimising correlated subqueries, and also can perform poorly with derived tables. e.g. In [this simple query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d87d18/2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM T) T
JOIN (SELECT * FROM T) T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID;
```

Even though ID is the primary key on `T`, the primary key is not used for the join as it can't be cascaded out of the derived table. Similarly sometimes when you write:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE Afield NOT IN (SELECT Afield FROM T WHERE AnotherField = 1);
```

MySQL does not necessarily materialise the subquery and use this, it will often rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM T T2 
                    WHERE T.Afield = T2.Afield  
                    AND T2.AnotherField = 1);
```

And the subquery is executed for each row in the outer query, so if you have a large number of rows in the outer query executing the subquery for every row becomes very costly. The solution is to avoid subqueries as far as possible. In your case you can rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE
        COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM    `citations`
        INNER JOIN `projects` 
            ON `projects`.`project_id` = `citations`.`project_id`
        INNER JOIN `users` 
            ON `users`.`user_id` = `projects`.`user_id`
        LEFT JOIN (user_stats_citations
            INNER JOIN user_stats
                ON user_stats_citations.user_stat_id = user_stats.id
                AND user_stats.type IN (69 , 70, 71, 75, 76))
            ON user_stats_citations.citation_id = `citations`.`citation_id`
WHERE   `users`.`role` = '0'
AND     `citations`.`created` BETWEEN 1360213200 AND 1360299599
AND     `citations`.`in_card` = '0'
AND      user_stats_citations.citation_id IS NULL;
```

With no subqueries there is no derived tables, or row by row execution of subqueries. This should improve execution time.

Answer (score 0):

What does this give you?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) numrows
  FROM citations c
  JOIN projects p
    ON p.project_id = c.project_id
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = p.user_id

  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT uc.citation_id
         FROM user_stats_citations uc
         JOIN user_stats us
           ON uc.user_stat_id = us.id
          AND us.type IN (69,70,71,75,76)
     ) x
    ON x.citation_id = c.citation_id
 WHERE u.role = 0
   AND c.created BETWEEN 1360213200 AND 1360299599
   AND c.in_card = 0
   AND x.citation_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This solution is taking like 2 seconds on production env. Also it return 0 numrows (correct result is 209)

Comment: I you substitute `COUNT(*)` for `COUNT(1)` it'll speed as it has not to retrieve the fields from the table

Comment: Yes, i figure it out that the alias was wrong. I replaced * with 1 but on production env. I have 1.060 seconds. So no improvement. Also I still get that for users table the PRIMARY index is not used.

Comment: Does user_stats have a compound index on (id,type)?

Comment: Not on both columns. There you have the indexes from user_stats


PRIMARY <= id
user_stats_user_id_index <= user_id
user_stats_type_index <=type
user_stats_project_id_index <= project_id
user_stats_month_index <= month
user_stats_year_index <= year

Comment: I added index on those columns, but no improvements.